# How to import pickled python object into Django view.py file

Tags: python, django

This file runs perfectly well on its own:

```
import pickle

with open('model.obj', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)

print(model)
```

But what I really want to do is to use model, which is a very large stored python dictionary, in my Django views.py file, like so:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from modeler.load_model import model

def page(request):
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'model':model})
```

However, when I try this, I get the error below:

```
 File "C:\Users\mmm\PycharmProjects\MyProject\modeler\load_model.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open('model.obj', 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'model.obj'
```

I don't understand why, because if I run the first file directly it works fine - the only extra step here is importing it into views.py (I tried including the entire load_model.py code within views.py at first, but got this error, so then tried it in this separate file and it worked on its own, so obviously the issue is that I don't know how to correctly load/import my python model objects or files within Django.

Comment: The django server will look in the project directory for the model.obj file. You need to provide the correct path or copy the object file there.

Comment: It is in the same directory as views.py. Should it be somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! Apparently, all I had to do was to put the absolute path to 'model.obj' in my open statement, not just the relative path, like this:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\mmm\\PycharmProjects\\MyProject\\modeler\\model.obj', 'rb') as f:
    model = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Obviously, that is not a good idea.  You can try fixing the path or try using `os.path.abspath` to get the absolute path of a file.

Comment: And you can omit double backslashes with R-string aka raw: `r'C:\Users\...'` or use slashes.